# Is Lua (Luvit) the same as Mongrel2?

Tags: web-applications, lua, luajit, mongrel2

I'm confused, is [**Luvit**](http://lua-list.2524044.n2.nabble.com/ANN-Luvit-Lua-UV-Jit-NodeJS-re-implemented-in-Lua-td7048032.html) the sames as [**Mongrel2**](http://mongrel2.org)?

It appears Luvit is similar to Node for JavaScript but the concept seems to be the exact same as Mongrel2.

If they are not the same, can someone highlight the differences in implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the most basic of the levels, they are both the same type of app: web servers. They both manage & answer requests comming from the web.

Some differences:

- In the source code, Luvit's core is Lua + some low-level stuff in C, whereas Mongrel2's core is all C.
- Mongrel2 supports 12 languages via plugins, while Luvit has no plugins: it's Lua-only.
- Luvit seems less "finished" (this is a personal opinion not based in any specific fact).